# Custom Font not working in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, uifont

I have added **`Avenir-Next-LT-Pro-Demi-Condensed_5186.ttf`** font in my resources. Also added the same to Fonts provided by application in my info.plist. 
In my code I have set the font like this,

```
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Next-LT-Pro-Demi-Condensed_5186" size:10];
```

But this is not working in ios 5 simulators and devices.

Comment: First check you have written the correct font name.

Comment: I have set the font name as Avenir-Next-LT-Pro-Demi-Condensed_5186 because the file name is same

Comment: @Akhildas That it not a correct assumption.  Check the name displayed when you open the font with FontBook.

Comment: If you can't install them then what good are they?

Comment: You can check with the class method "familyNames" for UIFont for the proper name of the font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this ,

```
The font name is not the font file name 

Avenir-Next-LT-Pro-Demi-Condensed_5186.ttf is a file name. simply double click the Avenir-Next-LT-Pro-Demi-Condensed_5186.ttf file it will automatically  open the font reader.Get the font name from top of the font reader navigation bar..
```

[image]

```
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next LT Pro" size:10];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check what is the font name it is at times different from font file name...

http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-custom-font-in-xcode.html

Got answer from [Add Custom Fonts In Xcode 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297926/add-custom-fonts-in-xcode-4-1)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps given below

1.Make sure when you copy the `font` the `"add to target"` check box  is checked.

2.First select  your `font` show in finder and double click on don make sure  your `font name` must be same as like `image`

[image]

Here font name is"eurofurence light"

3.Add font into `.plist` file

4.After doing all the things check your  font---

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Your font"]);
```

according to `font family` use `Bold` and `Italic`...

Hope this will help to you

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to this answer that not all the time this follows this rule. The best way is register the font in your application and perform a quick check and validate the font name.

Objective-c

```
 for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
    }
}
```

Swift

```
 for familyName in UIFont.familyNames() {
        for fontName in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName){
            print(fontName)
        }
    }
```