# unable to use custom font in ios?

Tags: ios, uifont

I am trying  to attach image, but I got some reputation problems, anyway I have added the font name in info.plist and I am trying to use custom font and I am trying to call it like this:

```
    UIFont *font;
    font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dyslexie Regular2 LEDU 1003 IN.ttf" size:45.0f];
    [myLabel setFont:font];
```

and also try this:

```
    myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dyslexie Regular2 LEDU 1003 IN.ttf" size:45.0f];
```

but both not working yet.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037091/custom-font-not-working-in-ios-5/17037402#17037402

Comment: Check the name displayed when you open the font with FontBook

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use .ttf extension while using font name.Make sure you have added TTF file to plist file of project[image: .]

Comment: have you added .ttf file in info.plist file corrresponding to "Fonts provided by application" key?

Comment: yes i did add the .ttf file in project, and also did add the key in info.plist.

Comment: when you set name of font in plist file you have to give its extension too like .TTF.have you done this? I am attaching screen shot to my answer to make thins more clear to you.

Comment: i did add .ttf extension file name in info.plist and also copy the font file into project resources. i dont understand why its not working;;

Comment: One more suggestion just reset your simulator then clean your code(command+shift+K) and then make a run.

Answer (score 0):

Add your font in bundle. Go to plist. Add a row  `Fonts provided by application`. It is an array. Add `Dyslexie Regular2 LEDU 1003 IN.ttf` in that. 
Then use this.

```
UIFont *font;
    font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dyslexie Regular2 LEDU 1003 IN" size:45.0f];
    [myLabel setFont:font];
```

Open .ttf file in Font Book. You will find font-name on top bar. Use that in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

The font name is not the font file name .Dyslexie Regular2 LEDU 1003 IN.ttf is a file name. simply double click the Dyslexie Regular2 LEDU 1003 IN.ttf file it will automatically  open the font reader.Get the font name from top of the font reader navigation bar..

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Get the font name from top of the font reader navigation bar" size:45.0f];
```

Comment: the font name is Dyslexie1 and i have tried this name too, but still not working i dont what is wrong with it..

Comment: myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Dyslexie1" size:45.0f]; Try this line

Comment: post me a your font link(Dyslexie Regular2 LEDU 1003 IN.ttf).i want to check with my xcode..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to drag the font’s ttf file in your resource folder and do this following entry in your info.plist file –

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>CloisterBlack.ttf</string>
</array>
```

UIAppFonts key accept a array so you can pass multiple fonts in it.

Now wherever you want to use the font in your application you can call:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Cloister Black" size:64.0]
```

Just make sure you give the real font name in above code. The font file name and its “real font name” can be different, so just open the font in FontBook app and there you can see the real name of the font.